# Using border-image on differing image sizes

Tags: html, css

All the examples I've found for using border-image are of fixed x and y. Is there a way to have the border image compensate for different widths or heights, using percentage?

Comment: If you are talking about slicing your image border-image-slice is property you need,you can specify in percantage , see here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about slicing your image border-image-slice is property you need,you can specify in percantage , see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do this with straight CSS. You're going to need some javascript to figure out how large the images are and set the borders accordingly. I've created a quick mockup on jsbin. [Check it out here.](http://jsbin.com/olocag/3)